# Java what is the type of `e` variable in multiple catch block?

Tags: java

Java provides to catch multiple exceptions in single catch block. but this is confusing for me. how can I know which exception is caught in this block ? and normally a variable in java has only one type. so how can `e` variable have too many types ?

Example

```
try {
    // codes
    // ...
    // ..
    // .
} catch(InturreptedException | FileNotFoundException | AnotherException e) {
    // how can I know what the type of `e` is ?
}
```

Comment: *If* you need to know the type of `e` you probably should not use a multi-catch.

Comment: that seems reasonable.  Also, you can also use the instance of test in an if block, in case you need something minor for a given type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` type is the most specific common supertype of the throwable types listed in the multi-catch clause.

If `AnotherException` is some subtype of `Exception`, then in your case it will be `Exception`, because `InterruptedException` and `FileNotFoundException` have `Exception` as the most specific common supertype.

More precisely, here is what the specification says:

> The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type as a union with alternatives D1 | D2 | ... | Dn is lub(D1, D2, ..., Dn) (§15.12.2.7).

`lub` is 'least upper bound' defined in section 4.10.4 of the Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html

Comment: @thanks, for example: if all exception types in multi-catch clause have `IOException` super type, so type of `e` is `IOException`. right ?

Comment: @1JustOnly1 If they all have `IOException` as supertype, and no class exists such that it extends `IOException` and it is extended by all the alternatives in a multi-catch, then yes, `IOException` is the type of `e`.